# Inconsistency constructing std::string from C-string vs. from another std::string

Tags: c++, string, constructor

**Why does the `std::string` constructor produce different output depending *only* on what kind of string it is constructed from?**

For example, consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    char cstyle[] = "01234567";
    std::string std = "01234567";
    std::cout << std::string(cstyle, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::string(std, 4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
0123
4567
```

I would expect them both to produce `0123`, or both to produce `4567`, but I wouldn't expect one to produce `0123` and the other to produce `4567`.

**Why this inconsistency?**

**EDIT**: This question isn't about which default constructor is called, or whether they do different things. They *do* different things, and different constructors *are* called. **This question *is* about *why* they don't do the same thing.** In other words, this is more of a philosophical question than a technical question.

Comment: std::string was designed long before C++ standardization and if redone today we might not repeat some of the choices made

Comment: "*this is more of a philosophical question than a technical question*" - then it is not a good fit for StackOverflow. If you want to know WHY the design is the way it is, ask the standards committee.

Comment: Thanks @Remy, I might just do that.

Comment: @M.M -- `std::string` (well, more accurately, `std::basic_string`) was designed during the initial C++ standardization effort, as part of C++98. It did not exist before the standards work began.

Comment: @PeteBecker you're probably better placed than anyone to answer this question

Comment: @M.M -- "better placed" does not mean "well placed" <g>. Yes, Uwe Steinmueller and I designed the original `std::string` (maybe before there was `std::`), but I don't remember the details at that level, and I doubt that anyone else does. I can come up with reasons for the difference (expansions on "different isn't the same"), but I can't say that those were the actual reasons. See the answer by Davis Herring.

Answer (score 1):

In each case, there is an overload with and without further integer parameters; we may consider them to be optional.  For the constructors from a `const char*`, the one additional parameter is the size (which is *needed* if the input is not null-terminated); if you want a starting **offset**, you can just write `std::string(p+off,sz)`, so there’s no point in offering it as a parameter.

When copying another `string` object, however, `std::string(s.data()+off,sz)` is circuitous and **unsafe**.  Without the source object, it’s impossible to prevent overrunning it with the offset or an explicit size; historically, `data()` has not always been (guaranteed to be) null-terminated, making such usage unsafe *without* the size.  As such, both a starting offset and size are provided for the copy-like constructors—in that **order** because that’s much more natural—and if you provide exactly one it must be the offset.

Comment: The constructor that takes `const char*` and a length is also needed when a string contains embedded nul characters.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Certainly, although that could be said to be another example of non-null-termination (maybe it does have a null character at the end, but how would you know it was the end?).

Comment: The point is that a normal C-string **is terminated** by a nul character; there's nothing you can do with anything beyond the nul. `std::string(const char*, size_type)` does not treat the pointer as a pointer to the first element in a C string, but as a pointer to an array of `char` whose contents have no special significance.